# Wrong answer for integer to word in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

First, I'm a beginner in python and programming generally. I'm trying to solve a leetcode problem that converts positive integers to word. My algorithm seems to be almost correct but with a few bottlenecks.
I don't know how to get rid of the `one` in numbers less than hundred, please see the output, which is making the conversion wrong.
I've been on it for a while with no luck and thought I should seek help. Thank you

```
def numberToWords(num):
    store = {1: 'One', 2: 'Two', 3: 'Three', 4: 'Four', 5: 'Five', 6: 'Six', 7: 'Seven', 8: 'Eight', 9: 'Nine', 11: 'Eleven', 12: 'Twelve', 13: 'Thirteen', 14: 'Fourteen', 15 : 'fifteen', 16: 'Sixteen', 17: 'Seventeen', 18: 'Eighteen',
            19: 'Nineteen'}

    word = ['Billion', 'Million', 'Thousand', 'Hundred', 'Ninety', 'Eighty', 'Seventy', 'Sixty', 'Fifty',\
            'Forty', 'Thirty', 'Twenty', 'Ten', 'Nine', 'Eight', 'Seven', 'Six', 'Five', 'Four', 'Three', 'Two', 'One']
    value = [1000000000, 1000000, 1000, 100, 90, 80, 70, 60, 50, 40, 30, 20, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
    if num == 0: return 'Zero'
    result = ''
    if num in store: return store[num]
    for i in range(len(value)):
        if (num //value[i] >= 1):
            y = num // value[i]
            result += numberToWords(y) + " " + word[i] + " "
        num %= value[i]

    return result

print(numberToWords(12345))
```

My Output: `"Twelve Thousand Three Hundred One Forty One Five "`
Expected Output: `"Twelve Thousand Three Hundred Forty Five"`

Comment: You would have to check if `y == 1` before recursing back into the method, but there's other cases to consider as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If value[i] is less than 100 then just don't print one. Here it is:

```
def numberToWords(num):
    store = {1: 'One', 2: 'Two', 3: 'Three', 4: 'Four', 5: 'Five', 6: 'Six', 7: 'Seven', 8: 'Eight', 9: 'Nine', 11: 'Eleven', 12: 'Twelve', 13: 'Thirteen', 14: 'Fourteen', 15 : 'fifteen', 16: 'Sixteen', 17: 'Seventeen', 18: 'Eighteen',
            19: 'Nineteen'}

    word = ['Billion', 'Million', 'Thousand', 'Hundred', 'Ninety', 'Eighty', 'Seventy', 'Sixty', 'Fifty',\
            'Forty', 'Thirty', 'Twenty', 'Ten', 'Nine', 'Eight', 'Seven', 'Six', 'Five', 'Four', 'Three', 'Two', 'One']
    value = [1000000000, 1000000, 1000, 100, 90, 80, 70, 60, 50, 40, 30, 20, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
    if num == 0: return 'Zero'
    result = ''
    if num in store: return store[num]
    for i in range(len(value)):
        if (num //value[i] >= 1):
            y = num // value[i]
            if value[i] < 100:
               result += word[i] + " "
            else:
               result+=numberToWords(y) + " " + word[i] + " "
        num %= value[i]

    return result

print(numberToWords(12345))
```

Output : Twelve Thousand Three Hundred Forty Five

Comment: This edit is much correct and easier but it's wrong for integers like 20014 as highlighted in the second answer, though I already edited it in my submission. Thank you both!

Answer (score 0):

Your core logic is fine. Essentially, your method breaks the number into powers of ten. (Quantity * value)

E.g. 2004 = 2*1000 + 0*100 + 0*10 + 4*1

Then converts into strings with the quantity and value joined:

E.g.
2 * 1000 + 1 * 4 = ('Two' + 'Thousand') + ('One' + 'Four').

Essentially 2 * 1000 is, Two `Thousands`. The bug is that in the last decimal place, your code converts 1 * 4 as One Four, because technically 1 * 4 is actually four ones.

So check if you are in the last decimal place, and omit the string for the value, which I have done in the code below.

There are other edge cases fixed. For example 20014 is Twenty Thousand and Fourteen, instead of Twenty Thousand, One Ten and Four. This is done by checking if num is in `store` every loop iteration instead of only at the beginning.

```
def numberToWords(num):
    store = {1: 'One', 2: 'Two', 3: 'Three', 4: 'Four', 5: 'Five', 6: 'Six', 7: 'Seven', 8: 'Eight', 9: 'Nine', 11: 'Eleven', 12: 'Twelve', 13: 'Thirteen', 14: 'Fourteen', 15 : 'fifteen', 16: 'Sixteen', 17: 'Seventeen', 18: 'Eighteen',
            19: 'Nineteen'}

    word = ['Billion', 'Million', 'Thousand', 'Hundred', 'Ninety', 'Eighty', 'Seventy', 'Sixty', 'Fifty',\
            'Forty', 'Thirty', 'Twenty', 'Ten', 'Nine', 'Eight', 'Seven', 'Six', 'Five', 'Four', 'Three', 'Two', 'One']
    value = [1000000000, 1000000, 1000, 100, 90, 80, 70, 60, 50, 40, 30, 20, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
    if num == 0: return 'Zero'
    result = ''
    if num in store:
      return store[num]
    for i in range(len(value)):
        if (num //value[i] >= 1):
            y = num // value[i]
            if num in store: # <-- Check if num now has a standard word
                result += store[num]
                break
            elif num > 9 and y > 1: # <-- check for last decimal place
              result += numberToWords(y) + " " + word[i] + " "
            elif num > 9 and y == 1:
              result += word[i] + " "
            else:
              result += 'and ' + numberToWords(num)
        num %= value[i]

    return result

print(numberToWords(20014)) # Twenty  Thousand Fourteen
print(numberToWords(121)) # Hundred Twenty One
```